# String slicing in array prints two characters?

Tags: c, arrays

The C program below print the first and last character of 16 words strings:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    char first, last;
    char *str = "abcdefghijklmnop";
    first = str[0];
    last = str[15];
    printf("%s", &first);
    printf("%s", &last);
}
```

The output I am seeking is a and p. But, when I run this code I get the output:

```
apa
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below lines will bring correct result

```
printf("%c", first );
printf("%c", last );
```

Comment: i would like the caution the OP against just accepting the first answer that works and moving on... if you want to become a good programmer, you have to understand *why* things work the way they do.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing understanding of pointers. When you assign a character to `first` and `last`, then those characters will essentially be copied to `first` and `last`. Since `first` and `last` are distinct variables, their addresses have no relation to the `char *str` pointer. Also, `printf("%s", &first);` (and the same with last) invokes undefined behaviour, since printf expects a 0-terminated string, but you pass one character only, after which there's no zero terminator.

What you can do is either use pointers:

```
char *first = str + 0;
char *last = str + 15;
printf("%s %s", first, last);
```

This will print `abcdefghijklmnop p`

or to print the two chars only:

```
char first = str[0];
char last = str[15];
printf("%c %c", first, last);
```

This will print `a p`.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables `first` and `last` are actual character values, not strings/pointers. You need to use %c instead. Try:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    char first, last;
    char *str = "abcdefghijklmnop";
    first = str[0];
    last = str[15];
    printf("%c", first);
    printf("%c", last);
}
```

The `%s` expects to get a pointer that points to an array of character values and keeps reading until it reaches a NULL character `\0`.

You can read more about this here http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch3x.htm and here http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output.

I find that the following C++ page has a better diagrams for visualizing pointers http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/.